# nginx: [emerg] unexpected "}" in configuration file

Tags: nginx

Below is the information given.

Error Message:

```
nginx[7787]: nginx: [emerg] unexpected "}" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/website.com.save:22
Apr 14 21:45:19 v2202004117607113208 nginx[7787]: nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
Apr 14 21:45:19 v2202004117607113208 systemd[1]: nginx.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Apr 14 21:45:19 v2202004117607113208 systemd[1]: nginx.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Apr 14 21:45:19 v2202004117607113208 systemd[1]: Failed to start A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
```

Code in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/website.com

```
server {


    server_name website.com www.website.com;


    access_log /var/log/nginx/website.com.access.log rt_cache;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/website.com.error.log;


    root /var/www/website.com/htdocs;

    index index.php index.html index.htm;


    include common/php73.conf;

    include common/wpcommon-php73.conf;
    include common/locations-wo.conf;
    include /var/www/website.com/conf/nginx/*.conf;


}
```

I tried checking for openings and closing of any tags or tiny errors. I cant seem to get it to work.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: The problem is not the file `website.com`, but `website.com.save`

Comment: Ah i do see that, do i just remove the website.com.save?

Comment: If you don't need it, delete it. Else you can move it out from /sites-enabled/ into some backup directory (or save a copy of it on the desktop and delete it from the server)

Comment: Thanks so much, it works :)

Comment: In most cases, this error is mostly due to missing semicolon at end of a line.